# Why is intentional form used in 「カラオケに行こうと誘われました」?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations, volitional-form

> 近所のひとにカラオケに**行こう**と誘われました。

I can easily understand what this sentence wants to tell me, but I don't really understand why intentional form is used here. 
I usually would just use plain form いく.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The form with *-ō* isn't just for intentions (the intentional mood).  It's also for invitations, i.e. an encouragement to do something together (the **cohortative mood**, like English "let's").

To understand the sentence, first we have to consider that the clause before と is a quotative argument.  Xと誘われました means "I was invited to 'X'", where I put quotes around 'X' to emphasize how the particle と works; it takes complete sentences and treat them as quotations.  That isn't done as often in English, but the structure is parallel to: "A neighbor invited me, like, 'let's go to the karaoke!'." – except in Japanese it doesn't sound casual or slangy; it's just a normal, unmarked way of expressing the idea.

Answer (score 10):

You should parse it this way:

> 近所のひとに『カラオケに行こう』と誘われました。

(*lit.*) I was invited by my neighbor, (saying) "Let's go to Karaoke."
⇒ My neighbor invited me out to Karaoke. / suggested we go to Karaoke.

---

> I usually would just use plain form いく.

You could rephrase the sentence as:

> 近所のひとにカラオケに誘われました。

I was invited to Karaoke by my neighbor.
⇒ My neighbor invited me out to Karaoke.

... but I can't think of a natural way to rephrase it using the plain form いく.